# How to initiate a watcher only after a page has loaded.

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a watcher that call a method like

```
watch: {
  'list.items' (n, o) {
     this.doSomething()
   }
}
```

The thing is, whenever the page loads, I push new values into `list.items` as:

```
methods: {
  fetchLists(){
    axios.get('/').then(
      res =>  {
       this.items.push(res.data) 
    };
  }
}
```

And I call fetchLists in created as:

```
created () {
  this.fetchLists()
}
```

The issue here is the watcher calls `this.doSomething()` when the page loads since list.items changes, but I wan't the watcher to only call doSomething after that initial page load

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a boolean data item `hasLoaded` to be tested in the `watch`, and set it when the fetch has completed, or you can use [`this.$watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) when your fetch has completed, rather than setting up a `watch` entry in your component.

It would look something like

```
this.$watch('list.items', (n, o) => {
  this.doSomething();
});
```

Comment: Do you have any examples on how to use `this.$watch` in mounted?  I have never seen that before